# Why are the materials resetting on certain keyframes?

Tags: materials

[image: On Frame 56]
[image: On Frame 57]

I am using a "copy location" Object constraint on this wheel, I don't know if that's what's causing it to reset. I tried every texture coordinate but top 4 of them glitches. This reset only happens when I am on frame 56-57 and 94-95.
[image: Material]
also I tried applying transforms but that didnt fix it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: An animation or .blend file would be very useful to see how it glitches exactly and debug it. My wild guess is that it rotates, but the rotation cycle is a multiple of 45° not divisible by 360°- geometrically it seems alright, because the animation of the object is compatible with rotational symmetry. However, the material doesn't have same rotational symmetry, and it shows. Consider this example, the cube has 90° rotational symmetry, so I rotate by 90° and go back to 0° and repeat. But the material is not prepared for that: https://imgur.com/T61e8Ge